# Нужна помощь с неРандомными числами С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, случайные-числа

Есть допустим 4 числа. К примеру 23,42,53,12.
Нужно случайным образом вывести только одно из них.
Как реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a[] = {23, 42, 53, 12};
cout << a[rand()%4] << endl;
```

Для ревнителей стандарта

```
random_device r;
default_random_engine e1(r());
uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0,3);
int a[] = {23, 42, 53, 12};
cout << a[uniform_dist(e1)] << endl;
```